# Background color issue, Chrome on Retina iMac. Hardware acceleration related?

Tags: google-chrome, background-color, hardware-acceleration

I'm testing out a site and I'm getting strange issue on latest Chrome version.
On a non retina iMac it displays fine, but on a 5k Retina iMac the background color is getting blocks of colour that are slightly off.

Attaching an image to demonstrate...

[image: Chrome Issue]

Hopefully you'll be able to see what's happening here. There are boxed areas of colours that are everso slightly different to the actual background color. The background colour is being set on the `body` only.

If you switch Hardware acceleration off the issue goes away.

Any experience with this or ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately this is an old known issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872 which is still not solved.

My suggestion is to try replicate the `background-color` by using an image as a background.

I have been in the same place before a while and this is how I solved it.

Comment: Thumbs-up for a cheaper solution than the one I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert on these kind of issues, but when the 5k retina iMac was issued with a tech-spec, there was alot of fuss and huss around the usage of **P3 color gamut**.

Specifically to the issue you are having, as you can see from [several](https://blog.conradchavez.com/2015/10/26/a-look-at-the-p3-color-gamut-of-the-imac-display-retina-late-2015/) different [sources](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3939770), some adjustments need to be done before your website will be able to show properly on the retina screen. On Chrome, BTW, it's still an open [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872).

To finish off, I got to say I **haven't** seen a best-practice to this issue, except from actually buying two screens, and **manually looking** at each picture/website.

Hope this helps, even for a starting point to this strange issue...

Further Reading:

- [What is P3 Color Gamut - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCI-P3)
- [Mac vs Adobe](http://www.astramael.com/)